# Using Google Maps directions API to generate commute info at specific times of day

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I'm trying to write an automated way to display commute times as specific times of day as we try to look for a home that is optimal for commute to work and to our kids' school.

I *thought* `departureTime` in `drivingOptions` was the correct value to set (looking for the equivalent of *Depart at* and *Leave by* in the Maps web site).

Simple pen to illustrate that changing the departure time from say 4am to 8am or `trafficMode` from `pessimistic` to `optimistic` is here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eELzVZ?editors=0010#0

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

  var dTime = new Date();
  dTime.setDate(dTime.getDate() + ((7 - dTime.getDay()) % 7 + 1) % 7 + 1);
  dTime.setHours(14);
  // dTime.setHours(8);
  dTime.setMinutes(0);
  dTime.setSeconds(0);
  console.log("Departure Time:", dTime)

  var request = {
    origin: 'Playa Vista, CA',
    destination: 'Manhattan Beach, CA',
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    drivingOptions: {
      departureTime: dTime,
      trafficModel: google.maps.TrafficModel.PESSIMISTIC
    },
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <div id="map" style="width: 50%; height: 100%; float: left;"></div>
  <div id="panel" style="width: 50%; float: right;"></div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong and is there a closer equivalent of *Depart at* and *Leave by* in the API?

Comment: Whomever down voted this, care to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DrivingOptions) You need to include a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID when loading the API in your request to use the `DrivingOptions` in the request.

It seems to work for me with a regular key as well, but not without one.

- [fiddle without key](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7psaqfL3/)
- code snippet without key

```js
function initMap() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

  var dTime = new Date();
  dTime.setDate(dTime.getDate() + ((7 - dTime.getDay()) % 7 + 1) % 7 + 1);
  dTime.setHours(14);
  // dTime.setHours(8);
  dTime.setMinutes(0);
  dTime.setSeconds(0);
  console.log("Departure Time:", dTime)

  var request = {
    origin: 'Playa Vista, CA',
    destination: 'Manhattan Beach, CA',
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    drivingOptions: {
      departureTime: dTime,
      trafficModel: google.maps.TrafficModel.PESSIMISTIC
    },
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML = "Duration of first leg is " +
        response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
      if (response.routes[0].legs[0].duration_in_traffic)
        document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML += "<br>Duration of first leg in traffic is " + response.routes[0].legs[0].duration_in_traffic.text + " (departing at " + dTime + ")";
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <div id="duration"></div>
  <div id="map" style="width: 50%; height: 100%; float: left;"></div>
  <div id="panel" style="width: 50%; float: right;"></div>
</div>
```

- [example with key](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_DirectionsServiceWithDurationInTrafficAndKey.html)

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DrivingOptions):

> **Driving Options**
>
> You can specify routing options for driving directions through the DrivingOptions object. **You must supply a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID when loading the API if you want to include a drivingOptions field in the DirectionsRequest**.

Comment: Thanks geocodezip - you're right - adding a valid API key does appear to change the output.  However, change the depart time (dTime in the example) makes no different to the result - 8am or 5pm is the same as 2am which given what it's like here, is wrong.

Comment: I was able to mostly do what I wanted using Python and the Google Maps REST API plus a hodgepodge of Google Sheets. etc - example here: http://i.imgur.com/rvqwj76.png - be so much better in a single web page.